# Pass parameter from other object as argument in defined type typescript. Object literal may only specify known properties, ts(2345)

Tags: typescript, types

I got a complex function with lots of parmeters, so I define my own type:

```
type foo = {
  int: number;
  str: string;
  bool: boolean;
}
```

So that I can use my arguments and callbacks more cleanly, I define my function like this:

```
function fooHandler(foo:foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}

function useCallback(foo:foo, callback: (foo:foo) => void):void {
  console.log('callback call:');
  callback(foo);
}
```

And then, in an excuting method, I can create an object, same as foo type, specifying the type or not

```
const myInlineObj = {
    int: 3,
    str: 'whatever',
    bool: false,
  };

useCallback(myInlineObj, fooHandler);
```

Output:

```
callback call:
src/main.ts:160
{int: 3, str: 'whatever', bool: false}
```

So works fine. I can also insert spare arguments in a type fitting object as argument, like this:

```
const int = 3;
const str = 'Hello';
const bool = true;
useCallback({ int, str, bool }, fooHandler);
```

Output:

```
callback call:
src/main.ts:160
{int: 3, str: 'Hello', bool: true}
```

But what I can't do is pass in another object parameter in the arguments even if fits the foo type.
For example:

```
useCallback({ int, str, myInlineObj.bool }, fooHandler);
```

I get the error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myInlineObj' does not exist in type 'foo'.ts(2345).
Naming the argument in the type as `myInlineObj.bool` wont work, so I do not know how to pass another object specific parameter as an argument, although the element fits the type of the container object.

I know that I can pass the whole object, and access the .bool as property inside the method, but if the object is big, does not seem optimal to pass the whole object, and would not be as clean as passing the specific parameter needed directly.

Any tips on how this is done? thanks.

Comment: What's the value of the extra prop? It's inaccessible to the receiver by definition.

Comment: I can do const bool = myInlineObj.bool; but I cant use it as an argument in useCallback({ int, str, myInlineObj.bool }, fooHandler); More than an accesibility problem its a typescript issue that I dont understand. If its by definition, mentioning that definition or what it consists in would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't really know which part of this you're trying to ask. Is it just a misunderstanding of how object shorthand works (in which case `{ int, str, bool: myInlineObj.bool }`)? Or are you actually trying to pass *extra* props, in which case why? Also you should look into https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html; `useCallback<T>(foo: T, callback: (T) => void)` is more reusable.

Comment: Its not an extra property, because the third component of the object is a boolean (check type foo), that is the one I am trying to pass, but that is a property or a component of another object (myInlineObj). I do not know I am undertanding your doubt correctly, but if it is an extra property, its not, the property is already defined on foo, and before the error I show 2 way the code works as long as its not get from another object. Thanks for your interest and comments

Comment: Right, I guess it's just the syntax thing. `{ foo }` is short for `{ foo: foo }` - when the prop name and the variable holding the value match, you can use this shorthand. `{ foo.bar }` doesn't make sense, you need the explicit prop name back: `{ bar: foo.bar }`

Comment: you got it bro. Post it and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's basically a typo, and with the question not being very coherent I'd recommend just deleting it.